# Validating Multiple Logins in vb6

Tags: sql, vb6

How can do I code in vb6 to capture the exact login time of employees in my system.

My system is daily time records. Each employee has login schedule like

```
8:00am - TimeinAM,
12:00PM - TimeOUtAM,
1:00PM - TimeINPM,
5:00pm timeoutpm
```

I want to get all the time of employees and compute their lates and undertime based from their login time and login schedule.

I'm very much concern with employees that has multiple logins in every session.
How do i manage that to  know if it is belong to TimeinAM,TimeOutAM,TimeinPM,or timeoutPM.

The structure of my table is I have these extra BreakTime Fields in every session. here's how it look:

```
EmpID | TimeInAm | BreakOutAM | BreakInAM | TimeOutAM | TimeInPM | BreakOutPM | BreakInPM TimeOutPM | Late | Undertime | Date |
```

sql is my database.

ANy one could help me , I will be very glad. Im working this for a month now.,

> Example of scenarios

```
EmpID=0001
Date=08-13-2013
8:00am - TimeinAM,
12:00PM - TimeOUtAM,
1:00PM - TimeINPM,
5:00pm timeoutpm
```

On this date he login for the morning session 2times

```
7:57:23 AM
7:58:10 AM //It happens when he thinks he didn't login. so he time in again
```

He logout in the morning at

```
12:03:01 pm
```

he login in the afternoon at

```
01:03:05 PM
```

and he logout at the afternoon at

```
05:12:27 PM
```

on this next scenario the employee has multiple logins in am session for eg.
this happens when he goes outside the company for transactions. it should be recorded as undertime in the morning., example is:

in morning he login

```
7:50:12 AM
```

then he undertime at

```
10:30:02 AM
```

and he goes back at

```
11:02:01 AM
```

and he logout in am at

```
12:02:01 PM
```

in the afternoon session normal login of employee is done

he login at

```
01:05:01 PM
```

and logout at

```
5:04:10 PM
```

this are some of scenarios which are possibly could happen.,
please comment if my examples are not cleared.

> Note: It's only me who determined that is belongs to TimeInAM,TimeOutAM,TimeInPM, or TimeOutPM. My only data is a list of logins of every employee everyday.

Comment: To improve your chances for an answer you need, provide relevant sample data and desired output based on it.

Comment: ok sir I will.,just a minute.,

Comment: What happens when a user forgets to clock out at the end of the day?

Comment: he will be undertimed ., since he only login and did not logout.,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand everything you're trying to do, but it looks like a business rule could be handy here: if you only take the first clock in every block of, say, 15 minutes timespan, you'll eliminate those "have I clocked in or not" cases.

Then you need to associate a clock-in/clock-out with a reason - from your example cases I would see:

- Start+End of day
- Start+End of break
- Start+End of offsite

Every system I've seen that does something like that, has a way for an "administrator" to manually override clocks, so you can fix missing end-of-day clocks.

If you can't have the reason built into the data you're consuming, I think you'll need business rules to be able to tell `break` from `offsite` - if a user clocks out between 11:30am and 1:30pm, it's lunch `break`; if it's after the first clock but before lunch break, then it's `offsite`; if a user clocks out after 4:30pm it's `EndOfDay`, and any clock-out before that but after user clocked back in from lunch, would be `offsite` again.

With the table structure you're shooting for, you'll need to update a record for each employee/date, every time they clock in/out.

You'll need code to fetch the appropriate record, and update it; you'll need code that determines in which field you're writing the clock time - that code could be a function taking the clock time and validating the business rules to determine the field - could be something like `Public Function GetFieldNameForClockTime(ClockTime As Date) As String`.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do. Create a function that would validate the clock times of an employee and shoot it to the appropriate field in database. In most of the employees, they go in and out from the company that's why they need to clock out before they leave the site and clock in again after they goes back to site.   Their clock time could be traced by a locators slip and manually update it to tables, but it's too strenuous thing to do.